# Fedora 29 repo issue

Tags: fedora

In the last weeks I started noticing some strange behavior in my system. I can not install application from "Software" gui and neither from CLI.

Now I am sure about this issue because:

```
[root@nuclear00 yum.repos.d]# dnf install cowsay
Last metadata expiration check: 0:19:10 ago on Mon 11 Mar 2019 01:01:59 PM CET.
No match for argument: cowsay
Error: Unable to find a match
```

I ran `dnf clean all` and `dnf upgrade` already, it executes but nothing seems to change.

The repo looks fine, as you see in the pic below. I haven't deleted the content of this folder (not that i remember at least).

[image]

Another sign of why I believe something is not right, is both when i open "Software".
It prints this error message:
[From askUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/925026/i-can-not-run-fwupdmgr-on-my-system) - `Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.fwupd'` Sometimes the short version, others the long one just like in this link.

Also, when trying to install "Telegram" from Software application, rpmfusion repo, the error is `Could not depsolve transaction; 1 problem detected:`

Unfortunately, without reading the full error message. Not even from the log, which should be `/var/log/dnf.log`. I can't find the log for the application `Software`, which again, it is the GUI version of dnf/yum.

dnf.log writes the log happening for the cli only.

Good thing: I enabled the `flathub` repo some time ago and at least I have now some more software, it is not a solution though.

I installed flathub because I noticed that from Software, everything disappeared. Software list was simply gone (and still is).

I re-followed this already but it doesn't seem it changed much:
https://rpmfusion.org/Configuration

UPDATE:
Do you see anything missing? Enabled/Disabled should be fine. Not that I want all of them enabled like source/debug etc.

[image]

Comment: The proper way to see the list of repositories that are enabled for use is to do `sudo dnf repolist`. A simple `ls -l /etc.repos.d` doesn't tell that a repository is in fact, enabled.

Comment: Do you have the standard `fedora` and `updates` repositories enabled? `cowsay` is available from the `fedora` repo.

Comment: you're right sorry. Updating the answer now with a screenshot

Comment: just noticed i miss fedora.repo completely :| - I'm installing it. It is now downloading everything after a `dnf upgrade`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're missing ALL of the standard Fedora repo files (including the base `fedora` but also `updates`, `updates-testing` etc.):

```
[yum.repos.d]$ ls fedora*
fedora-cisco-openh264.repo  fedora.repo                  fedora-updates.repo                  fedora-updates-testing.repo
fedora-modular.repo         fedora-updates-modular.repo  fedora-updates-testing-modular.repo
```

These files come from the `fedora-repos` package, which you have probably somehow managed to uninstall (or deleted the files):

```
$ rpm -qf /etc/yum.repos.d/fedora.repo 
fedora-repos-29-4.noarch
```

Instead of trying to recreate these files by hand or copying them from some random source, just reinstall the `fedora-repos` package. (If you don't have a working dnf/yum setup, you can always just install the rpm directly from your favourite Fedora mirror.)

Comment: A bit later, sorry. After this question and my answer, I reinstalled fedora-repos. I didn't update the question. Thanks for pointing it out and providing all that one would need ;) Back to some months ago, I don't know how I got it removed. I just don't. I realized long time after that I miss pieces of software..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment above I noticed I miss the whole `fedora.repo`. That's why nothing could be installed.

1. I searched it on github: [fedora-repo](https://github.com/coreos/fedora-coreos-config/blob/master/fedora.repo)
2. Created a file in `/etc/yum.repos.d/fedora.repo` and copied the content inside
3. Ran `dnf upgrade` and wait 'till it completed.
4. `dnf install cowsay -y`
5. `echo hello | cowsay`

   ```
   [root@nuclear00 yum.repos.d]# echo hello | cowsay

    _______
   < hello >
    -------
           \   ^__^
            \  (oo)\_______
               (__)\       )\/\
                   ||----w |
                   ||     ||
   ```

Comment: Now you should `dnf reinstall fedora-repos`; see the other answer.